# Counting arrays with gcd 1

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, recursive-algorithms, totient-function

I want to calculate the number of arrays of size $N$, such that for each of it's element $A_i, 1 \leq A_i \leq M$ holds, and gcd of elements of array is 1.

Constraints: $1 \leq A_i \leq M$ and $A_i$ should be integer.

For example:  If $N=2$ and $M=2$. We will have

```
1 1
1 2
2 1
```

3 different arrays whose gcd are 1.

Comment: I believe answer can be given as summation of some term [ which would use ETF (Euler Phi Function) ].

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! To get a good answer, you need to include more information in your question. What work have you done on this problem so far, and where do you get stuck? Also, your question should be clear. Are you looking at one-dimensional arrays of size $N$-by-$1$ (or $1$-by-$N$) or two-dimensional square arrays of size $N$-by-$N$, or something else? What do you mean by "calculate"--is a recursive or summation formula acceptable?

Comment: Given an array of size N-1 (with positive(?) integer entries less than or equal to M), it is always possible to extend it to an array of size N (with entries less than or equal to M) whose GCD of all entries is 1.  Moreover the entries possible for the last position depend only on the GCD of the first N-1 entries.  This suggests a recursive computation is attractive/feasible.

Comment: Yes. A summation formula is acceptable. And @RoryDaulton I have done some research on this question, and the question isn't actually this, I have reduced the orignal question to what I have asked. And I am talking about a linear array here.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. It would be better for you to edit your question to include all this in the question.

Comment: @hardmath How would I handle repetitions in recursive approach? And can you discuss your approach here.

Comment: What contest is this from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably easiest to use inclusion/exclusion.  If $M=1$, there is only one array of size $N$ and it has gcd of $1$.  If $M=2$, there are $2^N$ arrays of size $N$, all but one of which have gcd of $1$.  The one that fails is the array with $M=1$ with every element multiplied by $2$.  Similarly, if $M=3$, there are $3^N$ arrays of size $N$, all but two of which have gcd of $1$.  As $M$ grows, you get more deductions and need to worry about double counting the deductions.  When $M=6$, for instance, there are $3^N$ arrays that have a common divisor of $2$, $2^N$ arrays that have a common divisor of $3$ and $1^N$ that have a common divisor of $5$ to avoid a gcd of $1$, but you have counted the array of all $6$'s in both the $2$ and $3$ cases, so the final value is $6^N-3^N-2^N-1^N+1^N$  Extending to large $M$, you get $$M^N-\sum_{{p \le M}_{\text{ p  prime}}}\left \lfloor \frac Mp \right \rfloor^N+\sum_{{p,q \le M}_{p\neq q\text{  prime}}}\left \lfloor \frac M{pq}\right \rfloor^N-\dots$$

Comment: Can you suggest some recursive approach?

Comment: Recursion on what variable?  I think this approach is pretty simple.  You can't have $M$ too large or the numbers get enormous, so there won't be too many primes less than $M$.  I think there is another approach for large $M$ and small $N$, but I haven't thought about it.

Comment: Recursion on N?

Comment: I don't see an easy way.  An $N$ length string can come from an $N-1$ length string that already has gcd 1, or from an $N-1$ length string that has a higher gcd with a well chosen last element.  You force yourself to figure how many $N-1$ length strings have each gcd.

Comment: Using your inclusion/exclusion principle, I get $f(10,10) = 10^{10} - 9825699 + 2 = 9,990,174,303$.

Comment: In your example of M=6. There is a prime number p=5, and p<=M, so why we dont have a term for p=5?

Comment: @RaghavSapera:  you are right, fixed.

Comment: @hardmath:  RaghavSapera pointed out a correction that reduces the count by $1$

Comment: On a similar question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1063787/select-k-no-s-from-1-to-n-with-replacement-to-have-a-set-with-at-least-one-co-pr I suggested simplifying the answer to $$\sum_{n =1}^N \mu(n) \left\lfloor\dfrac{M}{n}\right\rfloor^N$$ where $\mu(n)$ is the [Möbius function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function)

Answer (score 1):

The arrays of size $N-1$ with GCD $K$ and integer entries between $1$ $M$ are in one-to-one correspondance with arrays of size $N-1$ with GCD $1$ and integer entries between $1$ and $\lfloor M/K \rfloor$ (proof: divide by $K$).

Therefore the number $f(M,N)$ of positive integer arrays with GCD $1$ satisfies the recursion:

$$ f(M,N) = \sum_{K=1}^M \phi(K,M) f(\lfloor M/K \rfloor,N-1) $$

where $\phi(K,M)$ counts the number of integers coprime to $K$ between $1$ and $M$, i.e. the number of possibilities for the $N$th entry if the first $N-1$ have GCD $K$.

**Observations about computing $\phi(K,M)$**

The function $\phi(K,M)$ agrees with Euler's totient function when $K=M$:

$$ \phi(M,M) = \phi(M) $$

and of course $\phi(1,M) = M$.

For intermediate $1 \lt K \lt M$ we can offer a couple of useful observations.  If $K_1,K_2$ have the same prime divisors, then $\phi(K_1,M) = \phi(K_2,M)$.  In other words the computation of $\phi(K,M)$ depends only on the prime divisors of $K$ (and on $M$).

Second we note that $\phi(K,M)$ is (weakly) increasing as a function of $M$, with $\phi(K,0) = 0$ and $\phi(K,1)= 1$.

Further the second argument can be reduced modulo $K$ in the following sense.  Suppose that $M = \lfloor M/K \rfloor K + R$ according to the division algorithm, $0 \le R \le K$. Then:

$$ \phi(K,M) = \lfloor M/K \rfloor \phi(K,K) + \phi(K,R) $$

In the above one can make use of the previous observation for the value $\phi(K,K)$.

Finally note that if $K$ is prime, then $\phi(K,M) = M - \lfloor M/K \rfloor$, i.e. all the values from $1$ to $M$ except the multiples of $K$.  More generally we can identify the count $\phi(K,M)$ by the inclusion/exclusion idea in Ross's approach, subtracting the count of multiples of $K$'s prime divisors individually, then adding back the count of multiples of products of prime divisors, etc.

In organizing a test computation of $f(10,10)$ I simply tabulated the values $\phi(K,M)$ for $1 \le K,M \le 10$.  It appears that only certain of the second arguments of $\phi(K,M)$ are needed in the recursion, just as only certain of the first arguments of $f(M,N)$ are needed.  In particular $M = 1,2,3,5,10$ arise from $\lfloor 10/K \rfloor$.

Comment: How do I calculate phi(k, m). Can it be linked with phi(k). Suggest some ways to calculate phi(k,m)

Comment: I've added some notes on $\phi(K,M)$ to my answer.  Probably an example $f(10,10)$ will demonstrate the comparison with @RossMillikan 's Answer, which might be a more efficient packaging of the same ideas.

Comment: Really helpful. Nicely explained!

Answer (score 0):

I want to calculate the number of arrays of size N, such that for each of it's element Ai,1≤Ai≤M holds, and gcd of elements of array is 1 ,with k as largest element

Constraints: 1≤Ai≤M and Ai should be integer.

For example: If N=2 and M=2 k=2

1 2
2 1

Comment: chutiya hai ka ?