# Count sets of size $k$ with GCD as 1

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

Given a sequence of $n$ numbers and we have to find out all the sets of $k$ numbers such that their $g.c.d$ is $1$.

More specifically, for a given value of $k$, we need to find the number of groups, each having $k$ numbers, such that the gcd of all elements in that group is $1$.

Two groups are said to be different if they have atleast one element which is at different indexes in the sequence.

**Note**: Gcd of a single number is taken as the number itself.

**Example** : Let $N=4$ and $K=3$ and sequence be : [$1,2,4,4$] then here answer is $3$.

**Explanation** : Three distinct groups can be formed

```
1,2,4 
1,2,4 
1,4,4
```

Note that the first two groups are distinct as the position of 4 is different in the two groups.

Note : Main point is K=1 or K=2 or K=3 only

Comment: Are you asking for a formula for the number of groups, or an algorithm to list (or count) the groups?

Comment: @Tad If their can be formula then its great else i only want to count the groups.No listing required

Comment: You could look at [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1054669/counting-arrays-with-gcd-1/1054722#1054722) and see if it helps.  The point is that you only care about whether the subset has a prime factor in common, then use inclusion/exclusion

Comment: @RossMillikan Please explain a bit more

Comment: A subset will have GCD of 1 unless all the elements have some prime factor in common.  In your example, the one that fails is $\{2,4,4\}$ because they are all even.  So you start with all the subsets and deduct the ones where all the elements are even, all the ones where all the elements are multiples of 3, etc.  But you have deducted the ones where all the elements are multiples of 6 twice, so have to add them back in.